# Force HiveServer2 to run MapReduce job

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, beeline

I am using hive-1.1.0.
Submitting queries to HiveServer2 via Beeline which are read-only and contain no predicates will cause HiveServer2 to try to read the data from HDFS itself without spawning a MapReduce job:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 100;
```

For very large datasets this can cause HiveServer2 to hold onto a lot of memory leading to long garbage collection pauses.  Adding a "fake" predicate will cause HiveServer2 to run the MapReduce job as desired; e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (my_id > 0 OR my_id <= 0) LIMIT 100;
```

By "fake", I mean a predicate that does not matter; the above example predicate will always be true.
Is there a setting to force HiveServer2 to always run the MapReduce job without having to add bogus predicates?

I am not talking about when HiveServer2 determines it can run a MapReduce job locally; I have this disabled entirely:

```
> SET hive.exec.mode.local.auto;
+----------------------------------+--+
|               set                |
+----------------------------------+--+
| hive.exec.mode.local.auto=false  |
+----------------------------------+--+
```

but queries without predicates are still read entirely by HiveServer2 causing issues.

Any guidance much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some select queries can be converted to a single FETCH task, without map-reduce at all.

This behavior is controlled by `hive.fetch.task.conversion` configuration parameter.
Possible values are: `none`, `minimal` and `more`.

If you want to disable fetch task conversion, set it to none:

```
set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none;
```

`minimal` will trigger FETCH-only task for

> SELECT *, FILTER on partition columns (WHERE and HAVING clauses),
> LIMIT only.

`more` will trigger FETCH-only task for

> SELECT any kind of expressions including UDFs, FILTER, LIMIT only
> (including TABLESAMPLE, virtual columns)

Read also about `hive.fetch.task.conversion.threshold` parameter and more details here: [Hive Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)